# jQuery delay stops working after first two "arguments(?)"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to delay each by instant then 300, then 600, then 900 etc

i want each element to slide in one after the other separated by 0.3s.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="first">

</div>

<div class="second">

</div>

<div class="third">

</div>

<div class="fourth">

</div>

<div class="fifth">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -o-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.first,
.second,
.third,
.fourth,
.fifth {
  width: 960px;
  padding:10px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  transform: translateX(-150%);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background:orange;

  .trans {
    transform: translate(0);
    transition:0.5s ease;
  }

}
```

jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".first").toggleClass("trans");
}).delay(300).queue(function(){
  $(".second").toggleClass("trans");
}).delay(600).queue(function(){
  $(".third").toggleClass("trans");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -o-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.first,
.second,
.third,
.fourth,
.fifth {
 width: 960px;
  height:50px;
  padding:10px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 min-height: 50px;
 background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  transform: translateX(-150%);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background:orange;
}

.trans {
  transform: translate(0);
  transition:0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="first">
  
</div>

<div class="second">
  
</div>

<div class="third">
  
</div>

<div class="fourth">
  
</div>

<div class="fifth">
</div>
```

I understand there is something called dequeuing? Although I do not know how to implement this into the code at all.

I tried adding `.dequeue()` before each `.delay()` but it didn't do anything, the elements third, fourth and fifth still weren't showing :(

Send help, please!

Here is the code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyawXm

I've added a snippet too.

I've only put jQuery in for the third class, but that doesn't even show, and neither does fourth and fifth when they're added.

Comment: are you trying to achieve like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbBMWK

Comment: Oh, you did it without using dequeue?? So it doesn't have to be used huh, hmm. Yeah that's what I was trying to do! Although the timing's off, I realised the 300 delay, derp, my misunderstanding of how scripts run, each one is 300ms after the one that's called, instead I was thinking of it as the delay for each is registered on load, can't explain but yeah thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this line: $(this).dequeue();
in every queue callback function, after you call toggleClass function.

Comment: Holy mother of.. thank you so much that worked a charm!!! I'm so happy now